# Conditionally Formatting A School Markbook Using VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for a faster way to format my Excel spreadsheet.  I have a large spreadsheet with 200 students' test and homework data on it.  I need the cells in the sheet to individually colour code their efforts (red, yellow, green) depending on if they hit their target grade.  I currently use three rules and copy those rules for every child with the same target grade.  It takes ages and if a child's target changes, I have to faff with the formatting too.  I need all the cells from `H5:AM27` to format in reference to the score in column `F`.  If they are on or above it, green.  3 marks or less below it, yellow, more than 3 marks below, red.

[image]

I know there's a way to do it using a `VLOOKUP` table but I can't find a concise explanation of what my lookup table needs to look like in order for it to work...

Anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select cells H5:AM27
2. Go to Home -> Conditional Formatting ->  New Rule -> Use a formula
3. Set the "highlight green" formula to `=AND(H5<>"",H5>=$F5)`
4. Repeat steps 1 and 2
5. Set the "highlight yellow" formula to `=AND(H5<>"",H5>=$F5-3,H5<$F5)`
6. Repeat steps 1 and 2
7. Set the "highlight red" formula to `=AND(H5<>"",H5<$F5-3)`